# Converting to timezone with $formatDate = $.PHPDate("U", date);

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, fullcalendar

I am using a jquery calendar called fullcalendar. When a user clicks a day they are sent to another page to create an event for that day. The date that was clicked is supplied as `date`. It is then run through the function below to convert it to UNIX time.

```
$formatDate = $.PHPDate("U", date);
```

I am using the javascript date library found here http://joncom.be/code/jquery-phpdate/

When I alert the date variable I get an output like this

> Tue Jan 04 2011 00:00:00 GMT+1100
>   (EST)

**This time is correct BUT after applying the $formatDate function the unix output is not in the correct time zone.**

Unfortunately it's returning local times relative to the server and I need it to supply times correct to the users timezone. I note that in the documentation there seems to be timezone references but in the documentation it says that timezones are "UNSUPPORTED"

Please... How can i convert my unix timestamp to the right timezone?

I should point out I have very little experience in javascript and come from a PHP/codeigniter background.

Thanks for your help.

Tim

Comment: That is an ActionScript library, not Javascript.

Comment: Sorry about that... I updated the link to what I think is the right site... I know this is javascript because I am using it in my jquery fullcalendar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a nice article explaining a lot about time zones in JavaScript: http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Javascript_Dates-The_Complete_Reference.

Bottom line is, the output will always be in the user's computer's (or at least, the browser's) timezone. You can test this (I think) by changing the timezone in your computer's settings. You will see the date changing in your browser as well (after a refresh, of course).

Is this what you meant?

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your reply. This is a great reference! Cheers. Unfortunately I am still confused. I know the var date is returning the browsers date. However when I run it through $formatDate = $.PHPDate("U", date); to convert to unix time it's returning the wrong date, or more accurately the date in Texas time (where my server is hosted)

Comment: Ah, right. Well, I'm pretty sure that if you add the timezone to the time when you create it (CST?), the "conversion" to your local time will do the rest. After all, it doesn't really matter which time zone you use: it's the same moment. You could also create the time in utc using the aptly named `gmtime()` PHP function and then creating your date with `Date.UTC()` in javascript. Finally, you could use `date_timezone_set` in PHP, but I think the UTC option is the most clean and portable one.